# Attaching files and uploading to server - Android Nougat

Tags: android, file, internal-storage, android-7.0-nougat

I am trying to upload files to server from my application. The user is allowed to attach the file from his internal storage. But some how the path I get from a Nougat phone is different from the standard `/storage/emulated/0/...` . in few phones I get `external_files/...` and in others I get `root_files/storage/999/....` . In this case I am not getting the right path of the file. How do we handle this scenario?

My code :

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        String filePath = data.getData().getPath();
        File sourceFile = new File(fileFields.get(i).getFileName());
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Uri` is not a file. `getPath()` is meaningless unless the scheme of the `Uri` happens to be `file`. That will not be very common on newer Android devices. Instead, the scheme will be `content`, and `getPath()` will be useless to you.

Instead, for both `file` and `content` `Uri` values, use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. This approach works all the way back to Android 1.0.

Comment: Can you please share me an example? I have tried using the `ContentResolver` but I get `NPE` on `cursor.moveToFirst()`

Comment: @SahanaPrabhakar: My answer does not involve a `Cursor`. I said to call `openInputStream()`. `openInputStream()` does not return a `Cursor`. `openInputStream()` returns an `InputStream`. So, `getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri)` gives you an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`.